# 'Open command window here' does not appear in context menu

Tags: windows-10, command-line, powershell, context-menu

I've encountered yet another one of Microsoft's pull-the-rug-from-under-your-feet tricks.

This time, the option `Open command window here` has disappeared from the context menu (displayed by shift + right click when inside a folder).

Instead, I now have `Open PowerShell window here`.

Of course, I can put aside all the important tasks that I have in front of me, take my time and study PowerShell for a few hours.

The thing is - I've got better things to do, and the command window utility is just an auxiliary tool that helps me to get by quickly. I'm not asking for anything more elaborated. Some of my daily tasks, like walking, eating and breathing - I do automatically. Same goes for the command-line window, and I would like to keep it that way.

Would anyone have any idea how to get that option back into the context menu?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Found the (surprisingly long) answer [here](https://www.windowscentral.com/add-open-command-window-here-back-context-menu-windows-10), so I'm leaving it here just in case it helps anyone else in the future...

Answer (score 0):

Here is a copy of the reg file I use to add both CMD and POWERSHELL to the background context menu in Windows 10:

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

;Add_Open_CMD_and_Powershell_to_Context_Menu.reg

;Right-Click Background only

;CMD Prompt

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\Background\shell\01MenuCmd]
"MUIVerb"="Command Prompts"
"Icon"="cmd.exe"
"ExtendedSubCommandsKey"="Directory\\Background\\ContextMenus\\MenuCmd"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\Background\shell\01MenuCmd]
"MUIVerb"="Command Prompts"
"Icon"="cmd.exe"
"ExtendedSubCommandsKey"="Directory\\Background\\ContextMenus\\MenuCmd"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\Background\ContextMenus\MenuCmd\shell\open]
"MUIVerb"="Command Prompt"
"Icon"="cmd.exe"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\Background\ContextMenus\MenuCmd\shell\open\command]
@="cmd.exe /s /k pushd \"%V\""

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\Background\ContextMenus\MenuCmd\shell\runas]
"MUIVerb"="Command Prompt Elevated"
"Icon"="cmd.exe"
"HasLUAShield"=""

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\Background\ContextMenus\MenuCmd\shell\runas\command]
@="cmd.exe /s /k pushd \"%V\""

; PowerShell

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\Background\shell\02MenuPowerShell]
"MUIVerb"="PowerShell Prompts"
"Icon"="powershell.exe"
"ExtendedSubCommandsKey"="Directory\\Background\\ContextMenus\\MenuPowerShell"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\Background\shell\02MenuPowerShell]
"MUIVerb"="PowerShell Prompts"
"Icon"="powershell.exe"
"ExtendedSubCommandsKey"="Directory\\Background\\ContextMenus\\MenuPowerShell"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\Background\ContextMenus\MenuPowerShell\shell\open]
"MUIVerb"="PowerShell"
"Icon"="powershell.exe"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\Background\ContextMenus\MenuPowerShell\shell\open\command]
@="powershell.exe -noexit -command Set-Location '%V'"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\Background\ContextMenus\MenuPowerShell\shell\runas]
"MUIVerb"="PowerShell Elevated"
"Icon"="powershell.exe"
"HasLUAShield"=""

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\Background\ContextMenus\MenuPowerShell\shell\runas\command]
@="powershell.exe -noexit -command Set-Location '%V'"
```